# Is there any way to prevent the ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT intent from overwriting the existing contact name?

Tags: android, insert, edit, contacts

When using the `ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT` intent, and providing a contact's first and last name as an extra, there is a problem whenever a user chooses to edit an existing contact instead of creating a new one. The existing contact's name gets overwritten by the data that was sent in the intent. While that's exactly what you want to happen when creating a new contact, it's terrible when it's an existing contact. There's been a bug report posted in AOSP for this back in 2010<sup>[citation needed]</sup>, but it hasn't been fixed yet.

Is there a way to work around this? I'd like to be able to use the same `ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT` intent and pass the name as an extra, but only have it used when creating a new contact. If editing an existing contact, I'd like the passed-in name to be ignored.